# How to automatically export multiple assets at multiple resolutions from a single SVG file with Inkscape?

Tags: vector, inkscape, svg, export, png

*Thanks for your comments. I realize my initial wording might have been confusing, so I have attempted to clarify what I'm looking for...*

---

I use Inkscape for designing and exporting app assets. These assets are created a 4x scale (which corresponds to `xxxhdpi` on Android or `@4x`on iOS). Let's assume I have *several vector icons* that are *256x256 pixels* *within a single SVG* opened in Inkscape. I need to export each of these icons at the following resolutions:

- **22.50 dpi** (`mdpi` for Android) -> *64x64 pixels*
- **33.75 dpi** (`hdpi` for Android) -> *96x96 pixels*
- **45.00 dpi** (`xhdpi` for Android, `@2x` for iOS) -> *128x128pixels*
- **67.50 dpi** (`xxhdpi` for Android, `@3x` for iOS) -> *192x192 pixels*

Doing this manually is really tedious. My question is thus: **Is there an efficient way to export one or several specific objects within an SVG file at multiple resolutions from within Inkscape?**

*Note*: I have hacked together a working, scripted solution that invokes [svg-objects-export](https://github.com/berteh/svg-objects-export) multiple times, but it is very slow and inconvenient, because I need to adapt the script every time I add an asset to the SVG file.

*Ideally, I'm looking for a solution from within Inkscape* ("Click and export", possibly for multiple selected objects at once). If that's not possible I'll take the next best option. A command line solution would be fine, as long as it's fast and automatically exports all assets in a file.

For quality reasons, I am also not looking for a solution to scale down exported PNGs.

Comment: Have you got a look to [Export Command Line Options](http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/CommandLine-Export.html)? The **--export-dpi** flag can help.

Comment: @PaoloGibellini Good hint, thank you. The Python script that I mentioned above is using this option as well. It seems that I would to have to specify each object manually with `--export-id`, though. I was hoping to find a solution that would just allow me to export all objects in the SVG. Such an option does not seem to exist, though.

Comment: Mmm... perhaps a simple batch file or shell file could be enough.

Comment: @PaoloGibellini Yes. I have a working shell script that does that, but I need to specify the ID of each object I want to export. I'm looking for a simpler (and faster) solution that would export **all** objects currently in the SVG at all desired resolutions without having to modify the script.

Comment: Ok, understood, I'm sorry at the moment I have no better ideas.

Comment: I don't understand the issue with the command line solution. For example, `inkscape my-file.svg --export-png=my-file-mdpi.png --export-dpi 22.50` works fine to me. You'd just need to create a 4 line script that exports at each size. The script can even take the file name as an argument so its reusable, if you do this regularly for different images.

Comment: @Scribblemacher Thanks. I realize I didn't properly state that I'm looking for a solution to export (multiple) _individual_ objects from within one SVG file. I have updated the question accordingly...

Comment: Ah, now I understand. Using `--export-id` as @KlaasNotFound mentioned seems like a perfectly fine solution to me if you give areas a predictable name. Personally I would just split it up into separate SVG files, and have a script run through each file in a directory. While this is probably a common use-case for Inkscape, it simply doesn't have the capability to do what you are asking (as is--I'm sure an extension could be written). I'd be curious if Illustrator has this feature.

Comment: See [Convert SVG file to multiple different size PNG files](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7442665/1366033)

Answer (score 2):

Create **clones** of your icons for each of the addition sizes you want to export. Give them **ID:s in Object Properties** and use the **batch export** option to save all of them in one click.

[image: inkscape clones]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try any of these extensions (didn't test them):

https://inkscape.org/en/~owenfromcanada/%E2%98%85androidvector (different concept, exports vectors for Android)

https://github.com/ChristianBecker/inkscape-android-export (what you've been asking for)

(a web search may find a couple more of those, key words 'extension Inkscape android')

Answer (score 0):

There is an App Icon Generator Extension by Carlos Vazquez, but looks like the author abandoned the project and do not accepts pull requests. The best fork so far:
https://github.com/firephreek/inkscape_app_icon_generator

Answer (score -1):

Check out this tool
https://github.com/redwarp/9-patch-resizer
It will automatically resize .png files into several densities.

Comment: "For quality reasons, I am also not looking for a solution to scale down exported PNGs."